# How to find average of top half of N numbers?

Tags: algorithm

Given N arbitrary integers, how to find average of top half of these numbers? Is there an O(n) solution? If not is it possible to prove that it's not possible?

Comment: Is the question supposed to relate to programming (i.e. solve this using a program)?

Comment: I donno. You can give mathematical formula if you have method. Its just an interview question.

Comment: This is one of the questions, where the interviewer wants to know whether the candidate can reduce real world problems to known algorithms. This is often more important than being able to recite the algorithms itself. Hence, I have a hard time to understand why this question was closed as off-topic.

Comment: I also can't understand why this is off-topic. It's a question that can be non-subjectively answered with an algorithm, clues being 'O(n)' and the tag 'algorithm'...

Comment: @BoltClock: I'm pretty sure that algorithms are part of the "programming" subject. Strictly speaking an algorithm is not a program, of course, but are we really going to throw out all the questions on searching and sorting methods, on the grounds that "quicksort is an algorithm, it has absolutely nothing to do with programming"?

Comment: @Steve: I voted to close and left that initial comment a **very** long time ago, before OP's clarification. That was my mistake, and I apologize for that. Casting the last reopen vote now.

Comment: @BoltClock: Sorry, I didn't notice how much the question had changed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, find a [median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) of the given array (it [takes linear time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm)).

Then, just walk through array and sum up all elements that are greater than the median.

Count how many elements you summed (`M`).  If `M < N/2`, then it means that several elements that are equal to the median value (namely, `N/2 - M`) belong to the top half.  Add to your sum that many median values.  We need this complexity because we don't know how many median elements (there can be several) belong to the top half: if we take them all, we can end up having summed more than `N/2` elements.

Now you have the sum of the top half of the array.  Divide by `N/2`, and you're done.

Comment: Or the code might be simpler if you do an extra O(n) pass and just count the number of elements equal to the median. That tells you how many equal-to-the-median elements to include in the average.

Comment: Even simpler would be to use that almost any algorithm for finding a median also finds a partition of the input list into a upper an lower half. Hence once the median is found all the elements in the upper half are already known.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a priority queue. Insert the elements into the queue maintaining a count of how many elements you've seen, `n` . Extract `n/2` maximum elements from the queue into an accumulator and calculate the average.

With a well chosen data structure behind the queue, such as a fibonacci heap, this will give you `O(n log n)` runtime, as insertion is `O(1)` and extraction is `O(log n)`.

Unfortunately not the O(n) runtime you were looking for, but with the data structure already implemented, this would produce very understandable straightforward code.

Comment: *Finding* the maximum is O(1) in a Fibonacci heap, but *removing* it (thus allowing what was the second-to-max to be found in another O(1)) is O(log n). If "insert" and "remove max" really were both O(1) in a Fibonacci heap, then it would be possible to use one to perform a comparison sort in O(n).

Comment: You are quite right, apologies, I've edited my answer accordingly. That pesky nlogn lower bound on sorting!

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously solvable in linear time, if you can find the median in linear time.
And finding a median in linear time is tricky, but possible. See for example the wikipedia article on [selection algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this:

Use Quicksort, select some pivot. 
This will partition your list into two sublist, one smaller than the pivot, one greater than that. 
If the size of smaller sublist is <= N/2, calculate the average say `a1`.
If  `size == N/2 or size == N/2 -1`
    you are done immediately.

If not repartition the greater sublist till the total size is N/2.

If size > N/2 partition the smaller sublist.

Repeat all till done.

P.S: you don't need to sort.